# Yii2 how to get the length of translated message

Tags: internationalization, yii2, strlen

In my project I am trying to provide dynamic sizing in one of my modules. I am trying to figure out in yii2 internationalization how can I get the string length of the translated text.

for instance:

```
 <?php 
       //I am getting the name from the database. Assume name to be "Hello"
       $name = $gettingNameFrom->db;

       //Now $name is equal to string "Hello"

       //The below function will dump the output to be int(5) as the length of hello is 5
       var_dump(strlen($name));

       //Now I want to apply translation to the above name in the db.
       // I have all my translation configured and working fine.

       echo Yii::t('app','{0}',[$name]);
       //I have configured fo french language.
       // the above output for "Hello" in french would be "Bonjour".



    ?>
```

Now how can I get the length of the translated text? I am unable to find any help online on this topic. Any help appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$translated = Yii::t('app', $name);
var_dump(strlen($translated));
```

Comment: No it doesn't help. Its getting the length of  **"string(37) "@MISSING: app.Hello FOR LANGUAGE fr @""**. But i have the translation provided in my translation file. When i switch my language it changes the text from Hello to Bonjour.

Comment: Try with `$translated = Yii::t('app', $name);`